# How can I remove 14 of 16 audio channels from a MOV file using FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, quicktime

I'm new to FFMPEG so I need some help from some professional users.

I have a relative simple task:

I have some MOV files with a single audio track that contains 16 channels. I want to remove the last 14 tracks and create a file with copied video (no reencoding) and just the first two audio channels. The 14 last tracks should be discarded.

I found a lot of tutorials for creating 5.1 files etc. but not what I need. Could someone please point me to the right direction or even post the command to accomplish this task?

Here is the info from the source file if that gives you any help:

```
    ffmpeg version N-94664-g0821bc4eee Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 33.100 / 56. 33.100
  libavcodec     58. 55.101 / 58. 55.101
  libavformat    58. 31.104 / 58. 31.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 58.101 /  7. 58.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : hexadecagonal
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'l:\Tag1 02092019\Stream 2 - Hilfsmittel\Teil1\Capture0000.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2000-01-01T02:00:52.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.player.version: 7.7.9 (Dev)
    com.apple.quicktime.version: 7.7.9 (1680.95.84)
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.gain: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.treble: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.bass: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.balance: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.pitchshift: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.mute:
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.brightness: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.color: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.tint: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.contrast: 1.000000
  Duration: 02:19:11.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 103685 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (LT) (apcs / 0x73637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown, top coded first (swapped)), 1920x1080, 85219 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 2500 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2000-01-01T02:00:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 LT
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, hexadecagonal, s32 (24 bit), 18432 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2000-01-01T02:00:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`-map_channel` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -map_channel 0.0.0 -map_channel 0.0.1 -c:v copy output.mov
```

Other channel manipulation options are available including the [`channelmap` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelmap). See the [wiki page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) for more examples.